# Data base for sign in and out app that tracks the time

Tags: android, database

I am creating an app that records your sign-in & sign-out. what database should I use to support offline and online use cases? I need to sync the data with the cloud too.

I have tried googling but I can not seem to find anything good

Comment: If your app is offline only, you can try using Room Database. Some other option would be SQLite, Realm DB. If your app gonna be online then you can try using, Google's firebase Realtime Database, Realm DB online.